# Can I install Pantheon on 15.10?

Tags: desktop-environments, 15.10, elementary, pantheon

There seems to be a lot of question regarding Pantheon, but they all somewhat contradict each other. Is there a simple way to install it?

Comment: So you are running Ubuntu and not ElementaryOS?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 15.10